# Creating vertical axis labels rather than rotating in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a line plot where the x-axis is actually a factor. I want the tick mark labels to be words and I want them to be displayed vertically rather than horizontally.

After searching I have been able to create a plot in which the axis labels are rotated 90 degrees but this isn't quite what I want.

A toy example is provided below:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = sample(1:10, 5, TRUE))

ggplot(aes(x, y), data = df) + geom_line() + 
scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:5, labels = c('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'phi', 'fum')) + 
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5))
```

Rather than having the labels such as 'foo' placed at a 90 degree angle I want them to be presented as

```
f    
o    
o
```

etc.

Thank you for any advice you can give. I realize that this can be done using the `plot()` function in base R however for reasons pertaining to my actual data I am set on using `ggplot`.

Comment: It changed the look of the last foo after submission.  Please take that to mean a vertical foo, i.e. the f is on top of the o which is on top of the o.

Comment: Now it's back to how it was originially intended.  Sorry, this is my first time posting.  I guess I should have given it a few seconds :-)

Comment: I dont think you can rotate individual letters (happy to be shown otherwise). But you can define you labels with a newline (`\n`) separator ie `f\no\no`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade comment to answer.

A workaround is to define your labels with a newline separator. The `\n` forces the next character(s) onto a new line.

Your example

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = sample(1:10, 5, TRUE))

ggplot(aes(x, y), data = df) + 
           geom_line() + 
           scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:5, 
              labels = gsub("", "\n", c('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'phi', 'fum'))) + 
           theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=20))
```

**EDIT**

Following Baptiste's comment a neater way is to define the labels with

```
labels = sapply(strsplit(c('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'phi', 'fum'),""), 
                                                    paste, collapse="\n")
```

This does not have the first and trailing separators.

The `gsub` line inserts a `\n` between every letter.

```
gsub("", "\n", c('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'phi', 'fum')) 
# [1] "\nf\no\no\n" "\nb\na\nr\n" "\nb\na\nz\n" "\np\nh\ni\n" "\nf\nu\nm\n"
```

This produces

[image]

I would prefer not to insert a separator before and after each word but don't know the regex - please feel free to update.

Comment: `sapply(strsplit(labs,""), paste, collapse="\n")` is one option

Comment: Thank you both very much!  I implemented this earlier and it looks great.

Answer (score 1):

not answering your specific example, but the more general case where labels are auto-generated (discrete scale),

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = c('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'phi', 'fum'), 
                 y = sample(1:10, 5, TRUE))

label_v <- function(lab){
  lab <- as.character(lab)
  sapply(strsplit(lab,""), paste, collapse="\n")
}

ggplot(aes(x, y,group=1), data = df) + geom_line() + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels=label_v)
```